# $route['written-qb/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] is not working

Tags: php, routes, uri, codeigniter-3

When I use uri segment 2, 3 it works but when add uri segment 4 it doesn't work.

URL should be like this...
http://localhost/maruf/written-qb/bcs/44th-bcs-english/how-has-the-phrase-digital-detox-been-explained-in-the-passage?

But it shows like this...
http://localhost/maruf/written-qb/bcs/how-has-the-phrase-digital-detox-been-explained-in-the-passage?
and both URL shows 404.

This is my route

```
$route['written-qb/(:num)'] = 'written-qb';  //works
$route['written-qb/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'written-qb/written_qb_details/$1/$2';  //works
$route['written-qb/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'written-qb/written_qb_answer/$1/$2/$3';  //does not work
```

My controller is...

```
    public function index(){
        
        $data['qb_list'] = $this->Question_bank_model->get_qb_with_category(FALSE);
        //footer data
        $data['main_content'] = 'written_qb';
        $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
    } // works fine
    
    public function written_qb_details($category, $slug = NULL){
        
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
        //data
        $data['qb_list'] = $this->Question_bank_model->get_qb_with_category(FALSE);
        $data['qb_info'] = $this->Question_bank_model->get_qb_details($slug, $config['uri_segment']);
        if(empty($data['qb_info'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['url_slug']       = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_slug'];
        $data['meta_title']         = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam'];
        $data['meta_description']   = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_post_meta'];
        $data['meta_keywords']      = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_post_tags'];
        //view
        $data['main_content'] = 'written_qb_details';
        $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
    } // works fine
    
    public function written_qb_answer($slug = NULL, $slug2 = NULL){
        
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $slug2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
        //data
        $data['qb_info'] = $this->Question_bank_model->get_qb_answer_details($slug, $slug2, $config['uri_segment']);
        if(empty($data['qb_info'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['url_slug']       = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_question_slug'];
        $data['meta_title']         = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_question'];
        $data['meta_description']   = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_answer_meta'];
        $data['meta_keywords']      = $data['qb_info']['qb_exam_answer_tags'];
        //view
        $data['main_content'] = 'answer';
        $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
    } // it does not work
```

and my model is ...

```
        public function get_qb_details($slug = FALSE){
            
            if($slug === FALSE){
                $this->db->order_by('qb_post.qb_exam_slug', 'DESC');
                $this->db->join('qb_category', 'qb_category.qb_category_name_slug = qb_post.qb_category_name_slug');
                $this->db->where('qb_exam_active',1);
                $query = $this->db->get('qb_post');
                return $query->result_array();
            }
        
            $query = $this->db->get_where('qb_post', array('qb_exam_slug' => $slug));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        public function get_qb_answer_details($slug2 = FALSE){
            
            if($slug2 === FALSE){
                $this->db->where('qb_exam_answer_active',1);
                $query = $this->db->get('qb_exam_ans');
                return $query->result_array();
            }
        
            $query = $this->db->get_where('qb_exam_ans', array('qb_exam_question_slug' => $slug2));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
```

in controller "written_qb_answer" and in rout
$route['written-qb/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'written-qb/written_qb_answer/$1/$2/$3';
does not work. It shows 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are overlapping :

```
$route['written-qb/(:num)'] = 'written-qb';  //works
$route['written-qb/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'written-qb/written_qb_details/$1/$2';  //works
$route['written-qb/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'written-qb/written_qb_answer/$1/$2/$3';  //does not work
```

Check the notes from the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Note 1 :

> Wildcards are actually aliases for regular expressions, with :any being translated to [^/]+ and :num to [0-9]+, respectively.

Note 2 :

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Note 3 :

> Route rules are not filters! Setting a rule of e.g. ‘foo/bar/(:num)’ will not prevent controller Foo and method bar to be called with a non-numeric value if that is a valid route.

Routes are not filters , when you use `(:any)` it means Anything ! why first and second works ? because you check first if it's numeric and for anything that wasn't captured in first one it gets captured in second one , witch means the 3rd one never works. It's like `if... else...` instead of `if ... else if ... else ...`